# Check username exists using PHP and PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I have a db.php file that has the following in it:

```
// db.php file
// creates connection to database

// DATABASE CONNECTION FUNCTION
function sql_con(){
    try{
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS,
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // log error to file and display friendly error to user
        ExceptionErrorHandler($e);
        exit;
    }
}
```

I have a signup page and i want to check if username already exists, so i call my `sql_con();` function beforehand to connect to database then do the below query

```
    // connect to database
    sql_con();

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `user_login` FROM `users` WHERE `user_login` = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute(array($username));

    if ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        $error[] = 'Username already taken';
    }
```

I'm very new to PDO and with the above i get the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in C:\wamp\www\signup.php on line 64
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\signup.php on line 64

Probably something very silly and I seem to confuse myself with PDO as I'm at the beginner stages. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Also I am not sure if this is the correct way as I'm new to PDO so if there's a more efficient way to do the username query check then please let me know.

Comment: @Paul, yes i include it using require_once. I have a config file and within that config.php file i use require_once to include my db.php, constants.php and functions.php file and that config file is loaded into all my site webpages. Thanks phplover

Comment: This is a very basic concept of **[Scope](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)**, this has nothing to do with PDO. If you aren't familiar with this concept, I suggest you reread the manual, and maybe get a good book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `$dbh` object is limited to inside the `try catch` block and your `sql_con()` function due to scope.

The correct solution would be to **remove the `try catch` block**, and ***return the `$dbh` variable at the end of the `sql_con()` function***.

Then:

```
try {
    $dbh = sql_con();

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `user_login` FROM `users` WHERE `user_login` = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute(array($username));

    if ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        $error[] = 'Username already taken';
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {

    //Do stuff with $e

}
```

Comment: Hi Truth, i will test this in a minute, can i ask, in the catch block above in your code, does it mean: if i cannot connect to db or execute query for any reason to catch the error if there is one ? thanks phplover

Comment: It means run this entire code, and if anything throws an exception, stop everything and run the catch block.

Comment: @Vahan: Read my answer. I told him to return the `$dbh` variable from his function, I'll highlight it so it's clearer.

Comment: so an exception is basically a way to say if i have a problem with any of the code in the try block whether it be query did not work for whatever reason or maybe something just went wrong to catch it in the catch block and do whatever i want with it which in my case i have a exception error handler to log errors to file. Also i was reading somewhere that using try and catch blocks is not recommended or something, hence why i did not use one, will try it now! Thanks php lover

Comment: Everybody are watching code first then read the text:)
So I didnt read the text after the code because i found it wrong sorry my bad:).But it will be better if you highlighjt it I am not first and I am not last.

Comment: @PHPLOVER: Yes, Exceptions are thrown to highlight exceptional cases (Database connection failed, there was an error in the query), the try catch block catches those Exceptions and handles them (the Exception object is saved on `$e` and it can be used to get information on the error. [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). Anyway, the `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` line in your code tells PDO to throw an exception every time it encounters an error. This is recommended as Exceptions are easiest to handle.

Comment: @PHPLOVER: Just be careful, an unhandled Exception will cause a debug backtrace to be printed, revealing ALL information on your PDO Object (including username and password!), as well as other information on the function which caused the Exception.

Comment: Interenet is on the blink tonight grrr, thanks Truth, finally i understand try and catch block, trying to find a good explanation online was not easy and you explained it well, also i understand about unhandled exceptions showing database details etc, hence why i create a exception error handler to display a friendly message to user but to log the error to file, but from what your saying, am i rite in thinking i should use try and catch blocks to handle anything when it comes to dealing with my database to ensure any possible error is handled properly and does not reveal important data? thanks

Comment: @PHPLOVER: Yes. Almost all methods of the PDO object or PDOStatement objects can throw `PDOException`s, so anything you do with your database connection (i.e. `$pdh` and `$stmt`) should be handled carefully with a respectful `try catch (PDOException $e)` block.

Comment: @Truth thank you, works great! not sure why someone said somewhere that you should not use try and catch blocks on all code that communicates with the database, rather weird, Cheers! phplover

Answer (score 2):

The `$dbh` variable is destroyed once the function is done executing.

You could try returning the handle:

```
function sql_con() {

    // your connection code

    return $dbh;

}
```

Then in your signup page:

```
$dbh = sql_con();
```

Depending on your needs, a better alternative would be to employ a [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) container.

Comment: Note that the `try catch` block has a scope of its own!

Comment: @Truth: No it doesn't. PHP doesn't offer any kind of lexical scoping. http://codepad.viper-7.com/P71eJY

Answer (score 0):

You are defining pdo in function an ist not visible out it.

```
function sql_con(){
    try{
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS,
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        return $dbh; //this 

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // log error to file and display friendly error to user
        ExceptionErrorHandler($e);
        exit;
    }
}


 $dbh = sql_con();
```

It will be better if you create a class for pdo abstraction.

```
$dbh = DB::getInstance();
```

Comment: `getInstance()` is definitely not the way to go. Especially if you're planning on a singleton!

Comment: @Vahan, i don't know OOP yet going to continue coding in procedural style and use PDO for database, not ready for OOP yet but thank you!

Comment: @Truth,In this situation yes it's not best, but in other situations it nice one , it's connects once  and you can use the connection   everywhere just by getting the instance of object.

Comment: Let me ask you this simple question. What would you do if you ever needed **2** database connections for 2 different databases? This is a very possible, very real-life situation. A singleton is not fit for database connections. There's a reason PDO was made OOP, each database connection as a different Object, **that's the point**.

Comment: @Truth , It's very simple I will add another method for second connection.
$dbh = DB::getSecondConnection();
public static getSecondConnection()
{
   if(!self::$secondConnection)
    { 
            self::$secondConnection = new PDO(......);
    }
    return  self::$secondConnection;
}
 This is nice yeah?

Comment: @Vahan no it isn't. It requires you to alter your DB class, and what if 2 days later you'll decide you need to gather information from 5 different database? You'll write an additional 3 functions? Where will this end? No. You write one function, and instantiate as many PDO objects are you want, passing those objects to the information gathering method. **THAT'S THE POWER OF OOP**. Not singletons. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what

Comment: @Vahan if you want we can gladly expand the subject on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php.